# Disable CSRF TokenMismatch for specific routes on Lumen

Tags: php, laravel, csrf, lumen

I'm using [Lumen](http://lumen.laravel.com/) Framework.

I have an external program who send a **HTTP POST** request every 2 minutes.

**I don't need any views**, so I would like to understand how disable CSRF TokenMismatch in Lumen for specific routes (I need it to be activated on some others) ?

Comment: Remove global `csrf` middleware and call it from within your controllers or routes directly. You can pass an array specifying included/excluded methods as well.

Comment: @revo Thank you. Is [this](http://laravel.io/forum/11-14-2014-disabling-the-csrf-middleware-in-laravel-5) what you are talking about ?

Comment: Yeah, just remove the entry from global Middleware and add it in route Middleware giving it a name. Then you can make it route specific

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could extend the `VerifyCsrfToken` class and add your routes to the `excludes` list.

Add this file called `VerifyCsrfToken.php` to `app/Http/Middleware`:

```
<?php namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends \Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken {

    protected $except_urls = [
        // your excluded URLs go here
        'example/route',
    ];

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except_urls) . '#';

        if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
        {
            return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
        }

        throw new TokenMismatchException;
    }

}
```

Then add the Middleware to the `bootstrap/app.php` file. You have to uncomment `$app->middleware()` then add it to it like this:

```
$app->routeMiddleware([
'csrf' => 'Laravel\Lumen\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken',
]);
```

Comment: yep, that is the way we were talking about in comments

Comment: Here's the official doc regarding this http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#csrf-excluding-uris

Comment: @Zl3n please look at my answer

Comment: Sorry, just saw that you are working with Lumen, I don't think my solution will work

Comment: @VishalSh I was trying to tell you, but I saw your answer didn't exist anymore. So still stuck at the same point ... Too bad, this solution of alex seemed good to me yet

Comment: I think you miss something in this solution? It is suggested everywhere 
https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/lumen/lumen-csrf-token-mismatch

Comment: Omg it works. I haven't seen **route**Middleware. I was adding into `$app->Middleware([`. Thank you very much for your time @VishalSh

Comment: Cheers! Also, I was looking at the lumen codebase, I dont know why i don't see any VerifyCsrfToken.php in the middleware folder https://github.com/laravel/lumen/tree/5.0/app/Http/Middleware

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97911/discussion-between-zl3n-and-vishal-sh).